# Joined Column left null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 classes.
First:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "region", schema="building")
public class Region {

    /**
     * id
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "regionid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "regionid", referencedColumnName = "regionid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<Polygon> polygonsList;

}
```

Second:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "polygon", schema="building")
public class Polygon {

    /**
     * id
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "polygonid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

}
```

i use need to connect some polygons to one region
When i insert new data with jparepository then Joined Column left null. 
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

need to delete `insertable = false, updatable = false` in JPA attribute